# Definition of Eigenvalue of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $T\in L(V,V)$. Definition of eigenvalue of a linear map $T$ is, $\lambda \in F$ is eigenvalue of $T$ if $\exists v\in V\setminus \{0_V\}$ such that $T(v)=\lambda \cdot v$. Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$. There are lots of equivalent definition of eigenvalue of a matrix. Different book define eigenvalue of $A$ differently, unlike definition of eigenvalue of $T$.

> $(1)$ **First definition:** $\lambda \in F$ is eigenvalue of $A$ if $A-\lambda I_n$ is singular (not invertible).
>
> $(2)$ **Second definition:** $\lambda \in F$ is eigenvalue of $A$ if $\exists v\in F^n\setminus \{0\}$ such that $A\cdot v=\lambda \cdot v$. Since $F^n\cong M_{n\times 1}(F)$, $A\cdot v$ makes sense.
>
> $(3)$ **Third definition:** $\lambda \in F$ is eigenvalue of $A$ if $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $\exists !\ T\in L(F^n,F^n)$ such that $T(e_j)=A_j$, $\forall j\in J_n$, where $A_j$ is $j$th column of $A$.

I want to prove they are equivalent, $(1)\Leftrightarrow (2) \Leftrightarrow (3)$. **Proof:** $(2)\Rightarrow (3)$ Suppose $\exists v\in F^n\setminus \{0\}$ such that $A\cdot v=\lambda \cdot v$. Since $A\cdot e_j=A_j$ ($j$th column of $A$), we have $T:F^n\to F^n$ such that $T(\alpha)=A\cdot \alpha$, $\forall \alpha \in F^n$. So $T(v)=A\cdot v=\lambda \cdot v$. Thus $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$. $(2)\Leftarrow (3)$ Suppose $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$. Then $\exists v\in F^n\setminus \{0\}$ such that $T(v)=\lambda \cdot v$. It’s easy to check, $T(\alpha)=A\cdot \alpha$, $\forall \alpha \in F^n$. So $T(v)=A\cdot v=\lambda \cdot v$. Thus $\exists v\in F^n\setminus \{0\}$ such that $A\cdot v=\lambda \cdot v$. Hence $(2)\Leftrightarrow (3)$.

I known following equivalent definition of eigenvalue of $T$, $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T$$\iff$$\text{ker}(T-\lambda \cdot \text{id}_V)\neq \{0_V\}$$\iff$$T-\lambda \cdot\text{id}_V$ is not injective$\iff$$T-\lambda \cdot \text{id}_V$ is not invertible$\iff$$\text{det}(T-\lambda \cdot \text{id}_V)=0$. It’s a standard result, $T-\lambda \cdot \text{id}_V$ is not invertible$\iff$$[T-\lambda \cdot \text{id}_V]_B=[T]_B-\lambda I_n$ is not invertible. In this case, $B=\{e_1,…,e_n\}$ and $[T]_B=A$. Hence $(1)\Leftrightarrow (3)$. **Is my proof correct?**

When we define the notion of characteristics polynomial (function), we first define for matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$, then we define for $T\in L(V,V)$ in terms of matrix, i.e $f_T=f_{[T]_B}$.

Comment: My third definition is not coherent feel free to edit it.

Comment: Should I use different notation for linear map associated with $A$? Because I’m only using $T$, which may be confusing.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: You can use $T_A$ for the linear map associated with $A$.